# Kubernetes : why is HostIP ignored in my pod manifest

Tags: kubernetes, port

From what I understand from the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.19/#containerport-v1-core) (though it is not quite clear) , the hostIP:hostPort couple can be used to expose a container in a cluster (meaning, other pods/services in the cluster can access my container via hostIP:hostPort). am I getting it right?

However, when I deploy a pod like this one for instance :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: firstpod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: container
    image: hashicorp/http-echo
    args:
      - "-text=banana"
    ports:
      - containerPort: 5678
        hostIP: 192.168.150.201
        hostPort: 5678
  restartPolicy: Never
  terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 0
```

Where 192.168.150.201 is the ip address of a node in my cluster (lets call it node1)
Most often, my pod does not get scheduled on node1. Evenmore, When I "force the pod to be scheduled on node1 (with nodeName for instance) I cant curl my app on hostIP:hostPort i.e.

```
curl 192.168.150.201:5678
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.150.201 port 5678: Connection refused
```

I have checked my pod is up and running (10.38.0.14 is firstpod ip address)

```
# curl 10.38.0.14:5678
banana
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You shouldn't ever need these settings.  You can configure a Service in front of your Deployment's Pods to allow inbound connections from other containers.

Comment: Thx @Maze for your comment. I am trying to understand theese settings independently from other solutions. I guess there is some usecase otherwise they would not exist?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `hostNetwork= true` so it the pod will share host's network space.

For example you can deploy following manifest:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: secondpod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: container
    image: hashicorp/http-echo
    args:
      - "-text=banana"
    ports:
      - containerPort: 5678
        hostIP: 10.156.0.46
        hostPort: 5678
  restartPolicy: Never
  hostNetwork: true
```

Where `10.156.0.46` is my host's IP and once deployed:

```
$ kubectl get pod -o wide
NAME        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP               NODE     NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
secondpod   1/1     Running   0          10m   10.156.0.46      worker   <none>           <none>
```

you can successfully curl it:

```
$ curl 10.156.0.46:5678
banana
```

Comment: Thanks Mariusz for your answer.Actually using the hostNetwork flag helps with curling the pod beause it allows to open the same port in host. However, the pod is not placed according to hostIP (try to deploy two pods as described in my yaml or yours)